# ASP.NET MVC 3, DisplayFor in View not producing monospaced output

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Using ASP.NET MVC 3...

NOTE: I was unable to get the three lines (Vowels, Full Name and Consonants) lined up vertically, the way they are actually coming out in my View display. It's easy enough to figure out the alpha characters and whether they are a Vowel (above) or a Consonant (below) above or below the name. The alpha "translation" used is: A-I = 1 to 9, J-R = 1 to 9 and S-Z = 1 to 8 in terms of numeric values.

From a View:

```
<!--
<table>
<span style="font-family:Monospace;">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;">Vowels</td>
        <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold; width:215pt;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Vowels)</td>
        <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VowelReduction)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;">Full Name</td>
        @if(Model.BMName == null || Model.BMName == "")
        {
            <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold; width:215pt;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BFName)&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BLName)</td> 
        }
        else
        {
            <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold; width:215pt;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BFName)&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BMName)&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BLName)</td>
        } 
        <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NameAllReduction)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right;">Consonants</td>
        <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold; width:215pt;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Consonants)</td>
        <td style="font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ConsonantReduction)</td>
    </tr>
</span>
</table>
-->
```

Example 1 ********

Outside of the table:

1 5 59 59

Albert  Einstein

32 92 512 5

---

Example 2 *********

Inside the table:

Vowels     1 5 59 59        34/7

Full Name Albert Einstein  63/9

Consonants   32 92 512 5    29/11

---

While the project was running, from the Model ABIPlusPhillips.BFName, .BLName (Big Al has no middle name and there is code everywhere to squeeze out middle name stuff, if no middle name is present.), .Vowels and .Consonants, I used a Quickwatch and TextVisualizer to look at the object and harvest the essential info from the object's properties, just prior to them being passed to the View. That info was copied and pasted into a text editor, with monospace font and gave a good vertical line-up of all the characters:

Example 3 **********

1  5   59   59

Albert Einstein

32 92   512  5

---

Finally, I bracketed the table with a  tag pair and got the same spacing problem (see Example 1), but all the characters in the table were red. In fact, I used the sam  bracket around the 'Outside the table', Example 1, and got the same results as Example 1, only in red.

It sure appears that the information embedded in the  is forced to be proportional, even though the surrounding HTML has been set up for monospacing.

How do I get around this problem?

Thanks to the Stack folks and to all the contributors...this is a great, informative site...

Marv

```
 I stripped things down to "barebones" as follows. The .cshtml page displays wrong, however the HTML source appears correct.


-------
.cshtml page that displays:

@model Numer.Models.ABIPlusPhillips

           @Model.Vowels<br />
           @Model.FullName<br />
           @Model.Consonants

Site.css:

body 
{
    font-family:Courier New;
    color:Red;
}

--------

------
_Layout.cshtml:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>

        <section id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>

    </div>
</body>
</html>

------

------
HTML Source from displayed page:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <section id="main">

       1  5   59   59 <br />
       Albert Einstein<br />
        32 92   512  5


        </section>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your talking about how a client renders something, therefore your first step is to look at the rendered HTML and see what is wrong there.

Comment: Thanks, MM, the HTML source is perfect: 
1  5   59   59 
Albert Einstein
 32 92   512  5

Comment: Then there is nothing wrong with the mvc part of it.  Your problem is with how the client is rendering it, which means it's like a CSS problem or some other issue (make sure your page validates)

Comment: I renamed the Site CSS file and made sure the pages reloaded. Still same problem. Not sure what you mean by 'make sure your page validates'. I did send that page to the W3C validator and it said it couldn't validate it...something about 'application/octet-stream not supported by this service'.

Comment: Well, that sounds like a problem right there.  Figure out the solution to that first, and it could fix your other problem.  Invalid markup is quite often the reason that sites render weirdly.

Comment: I just tried FireFox (latest) and got the same problem.

Comment: Bingo! I'm embarrassed. The fix, CSS style: white-space:pre. Thanks MM for your  interest and time.